# Enumerate all XefsTo a Segment in IDAPython

Tags: idapython

What is the best method to enumerate all xrefs to addresses in a particular segment? I came up with a brute-force approach (as seen below). The code scans each address in a segment and checks for an XrefTo the address.

```
seg_list = []
for seg in Segments():
    seg_list.append(seg)

# logic will be added to remove section that are code later
seg_list.reverse()
for seg in seg_list:  
    start = SegStart(seg)
    end = SegEnd(seg)
    while start < end:
        gen_xrefs = XrefsTo(start, 0)
        for xx in gen_xrefs:
            print hex(start), hex(xx.frm)
        start += 1
```

This approach is very time consuming if I have multiple large segments. IDA adds `DATA XREF` comments when viewing the data manually. Are these xrefs stored in an accessible way from IDAPython or is there another more practical approach to find the xrefs to a segment?

```
mem_15d:00973000                 dd 1C8h dup(0)
mem_15d:00973720 dword_973720    dd 101011Ch, 1000h      ; DATA XREF: mem_f08:00970678o
mem_15d:00973728 off_973728      dd offset off_970178    ; DATA XREF: mem_f08:off_970178o
mem_15d:00973728                                         ; mem_f08:0097017Co
```

*Note: Enumerating all xrefs from the code is not an option.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Heads function from idautils module.
So your code will look like that:

```
import idautils
seg_list = []
for seg in Segments():
    seg_list.append(seg)

# logic will be added to remove section that are code later
seg_list.reverse()
for seg in seg_list:  
    start = SegStart(seg)
    end = SegEnd(seg)
    for ea in idautils.Heads(start, end):
        gen_xrefs = XrefsTo(ea, 0)
        for xx in gen_xrefs:
            print hex(ea), hex(xx.frm)
```

Comment: And I thought idautils.Heads was just for code. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There may be xrefs to addresses which are not a Head, like xrefs to undefined data, or xrefs into strutures.